# Plugin com.google.dagger.hilt.android was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt

Yesterday, I was reinstall my windows and to save my project I pushed it on github, and before windows restarting everything was fine, and gradle was compiling correctly.
When I opening this project by VCS , I have this error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf63X.png)

I already tried to change gradle version , but nothing helps me
Screenshot with project structure(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQWIR.png)

Here's my gradle's module code

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYuDc.png)

---

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.firebasetesting"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
}
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
```

}
def nav_version = "2.5.3"

dependencies {

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.wear.tiles:tiles-material:1.1.0-alpha04'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2"

//Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"


// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"


// Network Dependencies
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3"
kapt "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

// firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
```

}
kapt {
correctErrorTypes true
}

---

build.gradle(project)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi0iW.png)

---

settings.gradle

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxIhC.png)

---

gradle-wrapper-properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPt8l.png)